# Glycogen replenishment after exercise

Tags: exercise, diet, nutrition

In the body, the liver holds between 90-110 grams of glycogen in storage, while skeletal muscle storage makes up another 400 grams.

If a person exercises and depletes both stores, when a carbohydrate source is consumed, which of the stores is replenished first?

Comment: What kind of conclusions would you draw from either process being faster assuming it was depleted somehow?

Comment: Would you say you eat before you workout and drink enough water? What other supplements do you take?

Comment: I eat good amount of carbs and a banana, no supplements just a multi vitamin once a day

Comment: What makes you believe it is one or the other.

Comment: I did read that "Your muscles are the secondary storage facility, filling up only when the liver has reached its storage capacity". Is this true? So the muscles will only take in carbohydrates when the liver is full?